# Can't get any info from ts video stream files

Tags: node.js, node.js-stream

I am trying to parse some m3u/ts files and get info about this files. I can get some basic info from http request with axios library but I want to get more info about videos I tried to implement
https://github.com/t6tn4k/node-mpeg2ts-parser
or
https://www.npmjs.com/package/inspector.js
and some others also but whatever I try I can't get any video info, I can't get it to work. For example I can give this m3u8 file http://wse1.resortcams.com/live-audio/hogsbreath2.stream_aac/chunklist.m3u8 to try to get any info about it, if someone can make an example how to make this work, please help

Comment: Show your code that you have tried already.

Comment: I did, the 2 links above have simple example code where you can insert your stream. I tried it and it didnt work.